# EventMachine not catching nearly simultaneous events

Tags: ruby, concurrency, imap, eventmachine

I'm using EventMachine to process incoming emails which could at times be very high volume.  The code that I have so far definitely works for emails that come in separated by at least about 5 seconds, but somewhere below that, only one email will be processed out of however many arrive.  I've tried adding EM.defer statements in a few different places which I thought would help, but to no avail.  I should also note, if it makes any difference, that I'm using the em-imap gem in this example as well.

The relevant section of the code is here:

```
EM.run do

client = EM::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, true)
client.connect.bind! do
  client.login('me@email.com', 'password123')
end.bind! do
  client.select('INBOX')
end.bind! do
  client.wait_for_new_emails do |response|
    client.fetch(response.data).callback do |fetched|
        currentSubjectLine = fetched.first.attr.values[1].subject
        desiredCommand = parseSubjectLine(currentSubjectLine)
        if desiredCommand == 0
            if fetched.first.attr.values[0].parts.length == 2
                if fetched.first.attr.values[0].parts[1].subtype.downcase != "pdf"
                    puts 'Error: Missing attachment, or attachment of the wrong type.'
                else
                    file_name = fetched.first.attr.values[0].parts[1].param.values[0]
                    client.fetch(response.data, "BODY[2]").callback do |attachments|
                        attachment = attachments[0].attr["BODY[2]"]                         
                        File.new(file_name,'wb+').write(Base64.decode64(attachment))
                    end
                end...
```

Am I somehow blocking the reactor in this code segment?  Is it possible that some library that I'm using isn't appropriate here?  Could GMail's IMAP server have something to do with it?  Do you need any more information about what happens in some given situation before you can answer with confidence?  As always, any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

**Update with Minimized Code**

Just in case anything in my organization has anything to do with it, I'm including everything that I think might possibly be relevant.

```
module Processing

  def self.run
    EM.run do
        client = EM::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, true)
        client.connect.bind! do
          client.login('me@email.com', 'password123')
        end.bind! do
          client.select('INBOX')
        end.bind! do
          client.wait_for_new_emails do |response|
            client.fetch(response.data).callback do |fetched|
                 puts fetched[0].attr.values[1].subject
            end
          end

        end.errback do |error|
          puts "Something failed: #{error}"
        end
    end...

Processing.run
```

Comment: I don't know ruby at all, but what happens if you get more than one email at a time?  You're only looking at `fetched.first`?  First of what?

Comment: Ah, thanks @Max, but unfortunately that doesn't solve it.  Each email is cast as "fetched" as it comes in, and "fetched" is an array with different bits of info about the email stored in different positions.  The subject line happens to be stored somewhere in the first part of that array, which is why I'm looking there.  All parts of fetched refer to the same email.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hate me for saying this, but refactor that pyramid of doom spaggheti thingy that makes Demeter twitch into something readable and the error will reveal itself :)

If it doesn't reveal itself you will be able to boil it down to the simplest possible code that reproduces the problem and submit it as an issue to https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine

However, EM isn't really supported any more, the devs went a bit awol so think about moving to https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid and https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid-io

**PS**

just saw this

```
File.new(file_name,'wb+').write(Base64.decode64(attachment))
```

is a blocking call afaik, try playing with this and you might be able to reproduce the issue. See https://github.com/martinkozak/em-files and http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine.html#defer-class_method on possible ways to go around this

Comment: Actually, at one point I reduced the code to nothing but printing the subject line of the email to the console, and the same issue still occurred.  So maybe I should submit it as an issue to EM, then.

Comment: @Free, possibly. Can you expand your question with that minimal code with which you provoked the error?

Comment: sure, it's posted now.  Thanks again very much for offering your help with this.

Comment: Np :) I'd send this issue to EM-Imap people at https://github.com/ConradIrwin/em-imap/issues since your code is basically their example at https://github.com/ConradIrwin/em-imap#idle so I'd say something is amiss there

Comment: I'm both relieved (it's not just that I suck!) and disappointed (this might be impossible!) to hear that, haha.  Okay, I'll do that, then. Thanks, @bbozo.

Comment: Chances are that the problem isn't just with EM-imap, but in your code as well, I'm pretty certain that file write can block given enough data, see SO questions about writing files in EM